# Search and copy from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to make a function that based on data from one worksheet will search another for comparison and copy from that to first one.

This is my function:

```
Sub kopiuj()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range

    row = 7
    If IsEmpty(Cells(row, 3)) Then
        MsgBox "Error1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(row, 3))
     If IsEmpty(Cells(row, 6)) And Cells(row, 5) = "cond" Then
          MsgBox "Error2"
           Exit Sub
     End If
     copyRng = szukaj2(Cells(row, 5).Value, Cells(row, 6).Value)
     Set pasteRng = Range(Cells(row, 8), Cells(row, 25))
     copyRng.Copy pasteRng
     row = row + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Function szukaj2(ByVal pp As String, ByVal p As String) As Range
  Dim PN As Worksheet
  Dim row As Integer
  Set PN = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PN")

  If pp <> "cond1" And pp <> "cond2" Then pp = "sth"
  For row = 7 To PN.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row Step 1
   If StrComp(pp, PN.Cells(row, 3).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 And StrComp(p, PN.Cells(row, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    Set szukaj2 = PN.Range(PN.Cells(row, 8), PN.Cells(row, 25))
    Exit For
   End If
  Next
End Function
```

I get Error 91

> runtime error "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your post and include a question (you didn't ask one). Also include in which line you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error will come on this code line

```
copyRng = szukaj2(Cells(row, 5).Value, Cells(row, 6).Value)
```

You need to use Set with object variables. Change this code line to :

```
 Set copyRng = szukaj2(Cells(row, 5).Address, Cells(row, 6).Address)
```

It should work fine then.